# Decimal to Binary

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, decimal, bitwise-operators

I have a number that I would like to convert to binary (from decimal) in C.

I would like my binary to always be in 5 bits (the decimal will never exceed 31). I already have a function that does it manually by dividing but that is hard to pad it to 5 bits.

Is there any easier way? Perhaps using bitwise shift?

I would also like the binary to be represented in a `char *`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an elegant solution:

```
void getBin(int num, char *str)
{
  *(str+5) = '\0';
  int mask = 0x10 << 1;
  while(mask >>= 1)
    *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
}
```

Here, we start by making sure the string ends in a null character.  Then, we create a mask with a single one in it (its the mask you would expect, shifted to the left once to account for the shift in the first run of the while conditional).  Each time through the loop, the mask is shifted one place to the right, and then the corresponding character is set to either a '1' or a '0' (the `!!` ensure that we are adding either a 0 or a 1 to `'0'`).  Finally, when the 1 in the mask is shifted out of the number, the while loop ends.

To test it, use the following:

```
int main()
{
  char str[6];
  getBin(10, str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will this break if the architecture uses a different binary representation?

Comment: @Kurian Well, it'll output the 5 least-significant bits in the int.  I don't know of any architecture that would have an unexpected representation of the numbers `0-31` as an int, though.

Comment: @AaronDufour What is `mask >>= 1` doing, is it the same as `mask = mask >> 1`? This should be along the lines of  `i=+1`

Comment: @AlexanderCska That's exactly what it is.  As https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/474dd6e2.aspx shows, you can add `=` to the end of most operators in C to get an assignment version.

Comment: @AaronDufour Thank you for the reply, I figured out that I don't understand the `!!(mask & num) + '0'`. Why do you add the zero. The `!!(mask & num)` does logical `and`, the `!!` produces `0` or `1` but why the `+ '0'`? I don't want to bother you too much but I tried to use the code you wrote and I find it really interesting. I am a Fortran programmer and I find C rather amusing.

Comment: @AlexanderCska `mask & num` is a _bitwise_ and.  Because `mask` contains only a single `1` bit, it returns 0 if that bit is `0` in `num` and something nonzero if that bit is `1` in `num`.  `!!` leaves a 0 as 0 and turns anything else into a `1`.  Finally, `'0'` is the number used to represent the 0 character in ASCII.  Adding 1 to it gives us the number for `'1'` in ASCII.

Comment: @AaronDufour thank you very much. Well this looks like type cast. For instance `for (k=0;k<10 ;k++) printf("%c \n",k +'0') ;` will print the numbers `0-9`, wheres if the `+ '0' ` is removed it will fail to do so. Very interesting!

Comment: @AlexanderCska In C the `char` type is simply a single-byte number.  `printf` (or, more accurately, your shell) knows how to interpret them as ASCII.  You can see that it is a number with `printf("%d\n", '0');`.

Comment: @AaronDufour My problem was that,  `for (k=0;k<10 ;k++) printf("%d \n",k +'0')` would not print `0-9` but would rather be the equivalent of printing `printf("%d \n",k +48)`. Therefore `printf("%c \n",k +'0')` seems suspiciously like a type cast. For instance FORTRAN does automatic type conversion when you do mixed mode arithmetic.

Comment: @AlexanderCska You're misunderstanding `printf`.  You hand it bytes and tell it how to interpret them with the format string.  In the `%d` version, you're saying "print this like a decimal number" and it does the appropriate divisions/modulos by ten.  In the `%c` version you're saying "literally just output this byte".  In both cases it is operating on something of type `char`; it just does different things with that `char`.

Comment: @AaronDufour well, I think that we start do diverge. I was asking wether you are doing a type cast. The answer to my question is that `int c=5; char i = c + '0';` would convert the integer `5` to char `'5'` i.e. type cast. Whereas `char c='5'; int i = c - '0';` would convert the char `'5'` to the integer `5`. I looked it up yesterday in the "C programming language" book. Because C guarantees that the char values for the digits '0' - '9' are contiguous, not true for letters.

Comment: @AlexanderCska The conversion between `char` and `int` does not work the way you think.  `'5'` is not equal to `5`, it is equal to `53`.  The "type cast" between `char` and `int` is simply a widening/shrinking - it pads with with 0s or removes the high bytes.

Comment: @AaronDufour thanks a lot for your answers. I made some research in the meantime and what you say is true. `0-9` correspond to `47-58`, therefore `int i = c - '0'`, where `char c = '5'` is equivalent to `int i = 53 - 48`. Or at least this is what I was reading online. Things are much more beautiful in FORTRAN!

Answer (score 15):

If you don't need leading zeroes, you can just use itoa(value, outputstring, base)

For example

```
char s[9];
itoa(10, s, 2);
printf("%s\n", s);
```

will print out

```
1010
```

Else you can just write a very simple function.

```
void tobin5str(int value, char* output)
{
    int i;
    output[5] = '\0';
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; --i, value >>= 1)
    {
        output[i] = (value & 1) + '0';
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[6];
    tobin5str(10, s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

will print out

```
01010
```

A more generic approach can be a function that ask you how much bits to convert.

```
void tobinstr(int value, int bitsCount, char* output)
{
    int i;
    output[bitsCount] = '\0';
    for (i = bitsCount - 1; i >= 0; --i, value >>= 1)
    {
        output[i] = (value & 1) + '0';
    }
}
```

Of course bitsCount must be a value from 1 to 32, and the buffer string must be allocated for at least bitsCount + 1 characters.

Comment: itoa() isn't defined in standard C?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is this:

```
unsigned int x = 30;

char bits[] = "00000";

bits[4] = (x & 1) + '0';
x >>= 1;
bits[3] = (x & 1) + '0';
x >>= 1;
bits[2] = (x & 1) + '0';
x >>= 1;
bits[1] = (x & 1) + '0';
x >>= 1;
bits[0] = x + '0';
```

Probably not the most elegant approach...

Answer (score 1):

For 31 values, instead of doing malloc to allocate a string, followed by the bit manipulation to fill it, you may just want to use a lookup table.

```
static const char *bitstrings[] = {
    "00000", "00001", "00010", … "11111"
};
```

Then your conversion is as simple as `return bitstrings[i]`. If you're doing this often, this will be faster (by avoiding malloc).

Otherwise, you don't really need any shifting (except to make writing your constants easier); you can just use bit-and:

```
char *bits = malloc(6);
bits[0] = (i & (1<<4)) ? '1' : '0';   /* you can also just write out the bit values, but the */
bits[1] = (i & (1<<3)) ? '1' : '0';   /* compiler should be able to optimize a constant!     */
⋮
bits[6] = 0; /* null-terminate string*/
```

There is a (maybe) micro-optimization you can do if you assume ASCII, by using addition. You can also use a loop here, but I needed two lines for the comment :-P. Performance-wise, neither will matter. All the time is spent in malloc.

Answer (score 1):

You can always divide and pad it to 5 bits  (did this to pad in 8 bits because printing a character like A would be the number 65 )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main(){
int binary[8], number, i; //for 5 bits use binary[5]
do{
printf("input a number: ");
scanf("%d",&number);
fflush(stdin);
}while(number>256 || number <0); //for 5 bits... 31 use number>31 || number <0
for (i=0; i<=7; i++)  // for 5 bits use i<=4
    {
    binary[i]=number%2;
    number = number/2;
    }
for (i=7; i >=0; i--)  //for 5 bits use i=4
    printf("%d", binary[i]);
number=0; // its allready 0.
for (i=0; i<=7; i++)  //for 5 bits use i<=4
    {
    number=number+binary[i]*pow(2,i);
    }
printf("\n%c",number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only working with 5 bits, why not use a lookup table?  Something like the following:

```
/* Convert nstr to a number (decimal) and put a string representation of the
 * lowest 5 bits in dest (which must be at least 6 chars long) */
void getBinStr(char *dest, const char *nstr)
{
  char *lkup[32] = { 
    "00000", "00001", "00010", "00011", "00100", "00101", "00110", "00111",
    "01000", "01001", "01010", "01011", "01100", "01101", "01110", "01111",
    "10000", "10001", "10010", "10011", "10100", "10101", "10110", "10111",
    "11000", "11001", "11010", "11011", "11100", "11101", "11110", "11111" };
  strcpy(dest, lkup[atoi(nstr) & 0x1f]);
}
```

Or a switch:

```
void getBinStr(char *dest, const char *nstr)
{
  switch (atoi(nstr)) {
    case 31:  strcpy(dest,"11111"); break;
    case 30:  strcpy(dest,"11110"); break;
    ...
    case 1:   strcpy(dest,"00001"); break;
    case 0:   strcpy(dest,"00000"); break;
    default:  strcpy(dest,"error");
  }
}
```

Or if that seems too long, maybe something like the following:

```
void getBinStr(char *dest, const char *nstr)
{
  unsigned x = atoi(nstr);
  dest[0] = (x & 0x10) ? '1' : '0';
  dest[1] = (x & 0x08) ? '1' : '0';
  dest[2] = (x & 0x04) ? '1' : '0';
  dest[3] = (x & 0x02) ? '1' : '0';
  dest[4] = (x & 0x01) ? '1' : '0';
  dest[5] = '\0';
}
```

I would normally favour one of the first two, but the last one might be better if for some reason the others are too big (such as code for small microcontroller).

These all assume you want the result left padded with zeros to 5 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char numstr[9024];
int i = 0;

void format(int n, int base);
void printreverse(char *s);

int main()
{
     int testnum = 312;    // some random test number
     format(testnum, 2);   // 2 for binary
     printreverse(numstr);
     putchar('\n');

     return 0;
}

void format(int n, int base)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        char tmp = (n % base) + '0';
        numstr[i++] = tmp;

        // If we put this above other two we don't need printreverse,
        // But then we will have unwanted results in other places of numstr if we can't reset it

        format(n/base, base); 
    } else
        numstr[i] = '\0'; // terminating character
}

void printreverse(char *s)
{
    long len = strlen(s);
    while (len-->0)
        putchar(s[len]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is C program to convert decimal to binary using bitwise operator with any decimal supported by system and holding only the required memory**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int n, t = 0;
    char *bin, b[2] = ""; 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    bin = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) + 2);
    while (n != 0)
    {
        t = n >> 1;
        t = t << 1;
        t = n - t;
        n = n >> 1;
        itoa(t, b, 10);
        bin = realloc((char*)bin, sizeof(char) + 1);
        strcat(bin, b);
    }
    strrev(bin);
    printf("\n%s\n", bin);

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int mask = 1;
void decToBi(int);

void decToBi(int n){
    for(int j=15;j>=0;j--){
        int result;
        result = n & (mask<<j);
        if(result)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }    
}    
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    decToBi(n);
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
char* to_bitstring(uint32_t val, char buffer[], int size) {
    buffer[--size] = 0;
    while (size > 0) {
        buffer[--size] = (val % 2 ? '1' : '0');
        val = val >> 1;
    }

    return buffer; /* convenience */
}
```

This will write SIZE characters to BUFFER:

```
char buffer[17];
printf("%s\n", to_bitstring(42, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
```

And will print:

```
0000000000101010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    int n,c,k;
    printf("Enter_an_integer_in_decimal_number_system:_");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d_in_binary_number_system_is:_", n);
    for (c = n; c > 0; c = c/2) {
        k = c%2;
        k = (k>0)? printf("1"):printf("0");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

int main(void)
{
int i, d , n = 1;
int store[10];

printf("Please enter a number to be converted to binary:\n");
scanf("%d",&d);

for (i=0;i<8 ;i++ )
  store[i] = 0;

i = 0;

do{
if(d & n ){
    n <<= 1;  //10
    store[i] = 1;
    i++;
}
else {
    n <<= 1;
    store[i] = 0;
    i++;
}

}while(n <= d);

printf("\n");
for (i=7;i>=0 ;i-- ){
  printf("%d",store[i]);
if(i == 4)
    printf(" ");
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a few lines of explanation.