# Int to Binary Conversion explanation

Tags: c, binary, decimal, bit-manipulation

My question is based on this post: [Decimal to Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911651/decimal-to-binary/7911777#7911777) and it's chosen solution.

I can get the chosen answer code working, but it only works for 5 bits. How do I modify this code to work for larger numbers, say 8 bits?

I tried just adjusting the character offset in the fist line from 5 to 8, but no success.

```
void getBin(int num, char *str)
{
  *(str+5) = '\0';
  int mask = 0x10 << 1;
  while(mask >>= 1)
    *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
}
```

and test with the given code, again adjusting the 6 to 9 to match the function above:

```
int main()
{
  char str[6];
  getBin(10, str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

but the output still only shows the first five bits and then gives random symbols. Can someone please explain what exactly is happening when I adjust those numbers so I can get this to work for an 8 (or any other size) bit conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void getBin(int num, char *str)
{
  *(str+8) = '\0';
  int mask = 0x80 << 1;
  while(mask >>= 1)
    *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
}

main()
{
  char str[9];
  getBin(254, str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

For 8-bit number you need array of 9 chars. Also you need to change mask, so it can mask all bits.

The mask for the most significant bit for a 5-bit number like `11111` is `10000` which is equal to `16` decimal or `10` hexadecimal.
Same thing for 8-bit number. The mask is `10000000`. Since the loop start with `mask >>= 1` the mask is shifted one to left `int mask = 0x10 << 1;` to compensate.
Thus to modify it for a `x-bit` number, define an array of `x+1` chars. Put `\0` at index `x`. Find the `x-bit` number where the most significant bit of it is `1` and others are `0`. The number is `2^(x-1)` (2 power (x-1)).

Comment: Thank you for the through explanation on the masking issue. I tried a few searches for the mask with the first value but didn't find any useful results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at english, sorry.
You need to adjust the local variable 'mask' too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getBin(int num, char *str)
{
  *(str+8) = '\0';
  int mask = 0x80 << 1;
  while(mask >>= 1)
    *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
}

int main()
{
  char str[9];
  getBin(10, str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

I want to explain why this code is working well.
but...
I'm not good at english...
I just hope it's helpful/

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer.

Too many magic numbers.

In the original, there are constants `5`, `0x10`, `6` that do not show there relationship to the goal of a `5` binary digit number.

Then when going to 8, the constants `8`, `0x10`, `9` were used.  Since `0x10` was not adjusted, code failed.

Instead approach the problem with a more general point-on-view and use code that eliminates or better expresses these magic numbers.

```
#define BitWidth 5

void getBin(int num, char *str)
{
  int mask = 1 << (BitWidth - 1);
  // skip the original shift left and then immediately shift right
  do {
    *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
  } while (mask >>= 1);
  *str = '\0';  // by appending at the end, no need for a magic number
}  

int main()
{
  char str[BitWidth + 1];
  getBin(10, str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Note: the above approach (and other answers) have a problem when `BitWidth` matches the `int` width.  But that is another issue easily solved by using `unsigned` math.