# C Convert Large Integer To Binary

Tags: c, linux, netfilter

I have IP addresses coming into a box in the form of, for example, 21211328.

I want to take this integer and convert it to its binary form.

The problem I'm getting right now is that my function spits out, based off of the example, -62674752.

This is obviously wrong, as it can't be negative and this isn't in binary.

The function I am using looks like this:

```
int toBinary(int decimalNo){
    if (decimalNo == 0) return 0;
    if (decimalNo == 1) return 1;                       /* optional */
    return (decimalNo % 2) + 10 * toBinary(decimalNo / 2);
}
```

I am using it as follows:

```
int num_converted = toBinary(iph->saddr); // convert it to binary
printk(KERN_INFO "BSADDR: %d", num_converted); // print the binary conversion to kernel for debugging
if ((num_converted & mask_array) == masked_sub){
        return NF_DROP;
}
```

And this is returning the incorrect output in my kernel logs as seen above.

iph->saddr returns the 21211328, and int num_converted = toBinary(iph->saddr); returns -62674752.

Comment: Is binary such a good way to present an IP address? The usual format is a sequence of four small decimal integers.

Comment: And of course you can't fit a 32-bit number into 32 bits if you want to use only 0 and 1 in the printed representation. If you do want binary, handle it as a string instead.

Comment: The reason you are getting a negative value is because of [two's complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). If you want to print it out as binary to the user you'll want to create a function for that.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! Yes, @ArndtJonasson, it needs to be in binary as I'm & it with a binary mask to test if it's the subnet range I want to drop. I will look into the string method though and see if it better fits the needs and solution. I'll also look into this two's complement to see if I can solve the negative value

Comment: @Crumblez If you know the exact size you can [do something like this](https://ideone.com/cXY5Zm)

Comment: just change your `int` to `unsigned int` or better `uint32_t`. BTW the convering function is an absurd. What is the decimal number? Is it a BCD number?

Comment: @PeterJ_01: that won't be enough. An unsigned int can only represent, what, 10 decimals? Then you are still short of another 22.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I got this converting function from another answer on Stackoverflow. How would you change this to still use ints and spit out the proper 32bit binary form?

Comment: Is it possible you are misunderstanding binary *numbers* and their *representations*? `21211328` is the decimal representation of a binary number (which is because that is how it is stored in memory). Other possible representations are hexadecimal, trinary, sexagesemal, and – indeed – binary. But the *number* does not change.

Comment: @usr2564301I think you are misunderstanding my problem. I need this number in binary. The fact that this is its decimal representation does not matter for the sake of this problem outside of converting the representation back to binary.

Comment: @Crumblez I think you do not understand the numbers in computers. Your function is the complete absurd. it tries to convert (binary)10101010101010101010101010101010 to (decimal)10101010101010101010101010101010 which is (binary)11111110 11111100 00111111 01110010 00001101 01010001 01001110 11100101 01100101 00001100 11101101 11100110 0010010 which is uint104_t :)

Comment: This is meant to run in the kernel? We'd better get this right. What's the type of `iph->saddr`?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Yes, this is running in the kernel. From what I can tell, iph->saddr returns an integer value with the decimal notation removed.

Comment: The answer should be something like `int` or `long` or `char *`. "Integer value with the decimal notation removed" is not a phrase that has meaning in the C language.

Comment: I'll be more specific. It's an int. This is an int because the decimal notation normally found in IP addresses has been removed. So it's not a char array or something else that would still have the decimals found.

Comment: Dotted notation is not decimals. OK, so it's an int. Then you just do `if ((iph->saddr & mask_array) == masked_sub)`.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson That doesn't work. I'm & with a binary mask array then comparing the output with the binary subnet I want to block. I tested it to double check

Comment: There is some conversion you need to make from network byte order to native. Your example 21211328 = 0x143a8c0 = 1.67.168.192, which most likely corresponds to the IP address 192.168.67.1. I think it's best if you take some existing device driver or module and study it thoroughly.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson where are you getting the conversion of 143a8c0 to 192.168.67.1?

Comment: One byte at a time. 0x1 = 1, 0x43 = 67 and so on.

Comment: See the very good answer by Luis Colorado further down.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with this! All helpful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ip addresses are normally represented (for human consumption) as quartets of individual bytes (four numbers separated by dots in network byte order) and not as binary sequences.

The address you post (21211328) represents the address `1.67.168.192` (which I guess is a wrong representation ---you need to consider that all ip addresses are in network byte order, most signifiant byte first--- of address `192.168.67.1`)

to successfully decode an ip address, you have first to consider if you machine will treat it in the correct endianness or you will have to switch bytes to be able to interpret it as a number.  The correct integer (in decimal) for the address `192.168.67.1` would be `3,232,252,673`.  This number cannot be represented as a `signed int`, because it has the most signifiant bit on, so it would be represented as a negative number.

To decode an IP address, you first have to convert the number you get from the socket interface to host byte order (endianness) by use of the `ntohl(3)` function.  Once you have the address in host byte order, then you have to convert the number to base 256.  This is quite easy, and you can do it with the following snippet of code:

```
unsigned long ip_address = ntohl(server_address.sin_addr.s_addr);
int i;

for (i = 24; i >= 0; i -= 8) {
    if (i < 24) printf("."); /* print the dot between the numbers */
    printf("%d",
        (ip_address >> i) & 0xff);
}
```

which I'll explain below:

The expression `(ip_address >> i) & 0xff` means to right shift the bits 24 to 31, by `i` places (or `24` places, `16` places, `8` places and `0` places) to the right.  So first we will put the 8 most signifiant bits in the place 0 to 7 (`24..31 => 0..7`), next we will do that for the bits next to them (`16..23 => 0..7`), and so on until the least signifiant bits, which are not shifted at all (`0..7 => 0..7`).  Once we have the bits we are interested in positions `0..7`, we mask them with `0xff` (which is a value with `1`s in bit positions `0..7` and `0`s elsewhere) so the and bit operator `&` will leave only the bits we have moved to the fixed positions `0..7` and will mask out all the others.  So we got a number between 0 and 255 finally, which is what we are printing.

In the case you indeed want to represent them in binary form, you can do it by slightly modifying the above code, just considering that instead of having eight bit numbers as digits you have one bit numbers as digits:

```
unsigned long ip_address = ntohl(server_address.sin_addr.s_addr);

for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
    /* In this case, we don't print the dot between the numbers */
    printf("%d",
        (ip_address >> i) & 0x1);
}
```

The mask this time is `0x01` which only masks the least signifiant bit of the number.

Finally, I wrote a complete program to illustrate both ways of decoding, showing in addition the use of the `ntohl(3)` function:

## ipaddr.c

```
/* 00001 */ #include <arpa/inet.h>
/* 00002 */ #include <stdio.h>

/* 00003 */ #ifndef DOTTED_DECIMAL
/* 00004 */ #define DOTTED_DECIMAL  1
/* 00005 */ #endif

/* 00006 */ #if DOTTED_DECIMAL
/* 00007 */ #   define NBITS    8
/* 00008 */ #   define SEP      "."
/* 00009 */ #else /* BINARY */
/* 00010 */ #   define NBITS 1
/* 00011 */ #   define SEP      ""
/* 00012 */ #endif

/* 00013 */ #define MASK    ((1 << NBITS) - 1)   /* 100..00 - 1 = 011..11, with NBITS `1` bits */

/* 00014 */ char *ip_formatted(long ip, char *sep, char *buff, size_t buffsz);

/* 00015 */ int main()
/* 00016 */ {
/* 00017 */     char line[1024];
/* 00018 */     unsigned long ip_netfmt = 21211328; /* this was the ip you posted (in network byte order) */
/* 00019 */     unsigned long ip_hostfmt = ntohl(ip_netfmt); /* this is the ip in host byte order */
/* 00020 */     printf("%lu => [%s]\n", ip_netfmt, ip_formatted(ip_netfmt, SEP, line, sizeof line));
/* 00021 */     printf("%lu => [%s]\n", ip_hostfmt, ip_formatted(ip_hostfmt, SEP, line, sizeof line));
/* 00022 */ }

/* 00023 */ char *ip_formatted(long ip, char *sep, char *buff, size_t buffsz)
/* 00024 */ {
/* 00025 */     size_t n;
/* 00026 */     char *s = buff;
/* 00027 */     int i;
/* 00028 */     for (i = 32 - NBITS; i >= 0; i -= NBITS) {
/* 00029 */         int digit = (ip >> i) & MASK;
/* 00030 */         n = snprintf(s, buffsz,
/* 00031 */             "%s%d",
/* 00032 */             i == 32 - NBITS ? "" : sep,
/* 00033 */             digit);
/* 00034 */         s += n; buffsz -= n;
/* 00035 */     }
/* 00036 */     return buff;
/* 00037 */ }
```

compile this code with the following commands:

```
$ cc -o ipaddr -DDOTTED_DECIMAL=1 ipaddr.c
```

to see output in dotted decimal, and

```
$ cc -o ipaddr -DDOTTED_DECIMAL=0 ipaddr.c
```

to see output in binary digits.

(I included line numbers, so references to the code can be used, and commented, so you can directly compile the code by cut and paste it)

Comment: Thank you for the very in-depth answer! This helped a lot in my understanding of these principals, appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *getBin( unsigned long val) {
    static char buf[33];
    int i;

    buf[32]='\0';
    for(i=31; i>=0; i--){
        buf[i] = val & 1?'1':'0';
        val/=2;
    }
    return buf;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long ip=0x80e2d301;    
    printf( " ip:%08lx, bin:%sB\n", (unsigned long)ip, getBin(ip) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ?? The " ended up in that URL – weird. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911777

Comment: @lonejack What happens if you call this Function more than Once?

Comment: @Michi the function store the value on a static register. If you call this two (or more) times the value will be overwritten.
it is possible to modify it passing a destination:
char * getBin( char * dest, uint32_t val){}

Comment: @usr2564301 I didn't copy

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I checked it, two examples:

ip:80e2d301, bin:10000000111000101101001100000001B,

ip:00000006, bin:00000000000000000000000000000110B

Comment: @lonejack That is good. Now that you know, What's the story here (what is the benefit) with `static` ? (Hope is not to help return buf). Why not [Something likeThis](https://pastebin.com/raw/WK5figLc) ?

Comment: `%08x` is not certainly the matching specifier for `uint32_t`.  Research `<inttypes.h>` and `PRIx32`

Comment: @Michi static means that the buffer will remain available also when we exit from function. If you remove "static" for sure you'll obtain an error: this because the buffer becomes local and the "return buf" will return the pointer to a variable that no longer exist.

Comment: @loneejack You did not understood my Point. But thank you for your Explanation:).