# C Language Access memory as binary

Tags: c, memory, binary

Basically what I am asking is:

When I do a + b = c , c is stored in memory as binary.

How to access that part of the memory and retrieve c in that form and use it later.

Example: 2 + 3 = 5 , 5 is stores as "0101" . variable d, will retrieve the result "0101" and I will be able to output it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911651/decimal-to-binary)

Comment: Also, "retrieving" a value at `c` is just getting a pointer, i.e. `int *d = &c;`

Comment: @ahota *"retrieving" a value at `c` is [...]* – No. *`int *d = &c;`* is defining a variable `d` of type pointer to `int` and initializing it with the address of variable `c`.

Comment: I suppose I could have been more exact with that statement. Ultimately the point was that there is no special retrieval process other than using pointers.

Comment: If c is declared as an `int` and is 5 and you're on a modern 32 or 64-bit system, it's probably stored as 00000000000000000000000000000101. What do you want displayed?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I want to ouput 00000000000000000000000000000101 , without using any conversion, just the one made by the processor itself

Comment: @BradLorenz as soon as you want to output in such a way, you already need to convert every bit of the number into a char(0 -> '0', 1 -> '1'), or you will not be able to see the characters on the screen (or in a text file).

Comment: "_without using any conversion, just the one made by the processor itself_" - As no CPU, not even GPUs or the famous TMS34020  has instructions to draw glyphs from a bitvector onto a screen, this is impossible.

Comment: *"unclear what you're asking"* ok, what part of the question didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mess up the ways data is represented in a computer world. **all** data in memory is binary, consisting of bits, which are grouped in words. On 64-bit system a memory word consist of 64 bits. Every bit can have value of 'on' or 'off' => '1' or '0';

Variables are just symbolic names of the places in memory where the data is kept. I.e.

```
int i;
```

reserves a place in memory sufficient to contain an integer value in 'c'. By default, such a value in 'c' usually (depending on the operating system) is 32 bit wide.

```
int a, b, c;
a = 2;
b = 3;
c = a + b;
```

all variables above are related to different places in memory. 'c' will contain 5 as long as the place in memory exists and until someone changes it to a different value.

```
printf ("%d", c);
```

The above function  **converts** binary value of 'c' into a character value of '5' and prints it on the screen. This way you will see '5' on the screen. '%d' tells the function that 'c' is a decimal integer value.

Every character by itself is also represented by an int value, though in ascii encoding scheme it only needs '8' bits to be represented. So, character '5' is encoded as an int value of 53.

```
 print("%c", '5') // will print '5'
 print("%d", '5') // will print 53
```

It is more difficult to print binary numbers bit by bit. There is no such format specifier in printf. So, you need to write a small program which would analyze the number bit by bit and print it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a=2, b= 3, c = a+b;

  for (int bit = 31; bit >= 0; --bit) {
     if (((c >> bit) & 1) == 0)
        printf("0");
     else
        printf("1");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

and the result is: 00000000000000000000000000000101

Comment: "… in a computer world. all data in memory is binary …" - Well, some nit-picking as it is unclear what OP is actually after (I agree about the "confuse" part, though). Let aside analog computers and other classic computers which used decimal or othe number systems internally, almost all Flash memory used for mass storage today uses quaterny or higher level internal rrepresentation.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use pointers for that!

```
int *c =(int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
*c = a+b;
```

and to retrieve the value later, do this:

```
int value = *c;
```

The reason C is used for hardware and OS is in fact this. You can access memory directly and modify it.

Please note that when you save the value, it will be saved as a binary anyways.

When you retrieve it, you can't directly print it as binary. So, you can use functions like this https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-number-decimal-to-binary-recursion/ to convert it to binary and print it.

Comment: "... when you save the value, it will be saved as a binary anyways." OP seems to believe that means you can retrieve those individual bits. (Which you *can*, admittedly, but not by reading the individual 0s and 1s.)

Comment: @Swordfish I guess that sentence was wrong. since it is still saved in the memory as a binary value. Edited it.